# How to add multiple contact numbers within a single textbox and also a X(clear) button for each of the text added using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add multiple contact numbers within a single textbox and also a X(clear) button for each of the text added using javascript?

Below is a part of my HTML page

```
Contact No:<input type="text" id="no"><input type="button" value="ADD" id="add" onclick="javascript:addContact();">
<input type="text"  id="text_name"  style="width: 300px;height:50px;" />
```

Here is my javascript function

```
function addContact(){

 var temp = document.createElement("input");
temp.innerHTML="<input type='search' value='' alt='clear' >";

 var contact_added=document.getElementById("text_name").value;
 var contact=document.getElementById("no").value;

 document.getElementById("text_name").value=contact+temp+contact_added;

}
```

This is what I get as my output

![My output]

However what I need is that for every text that I enter,it should be follow by a clear so that I can clear that selected block of text

Comment: You create an input, and put an "<input>" in it, thats wrong html

Comment: What do you suggest?Any idea how I can get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addContact(){
 temp="<input type='search' value=''.      alt='clear' >"; 
var contact_added=document.getElementById("text_name").value; 
var contact=document.getElementById("no").value;
 document.getElementById("text_name").value=contact+temp+contact_added;
 }
```

However this doesnt solve your problem. I think it isnt a good idea, doing this with inputs and buttons. This only makes it complicated.
At first make a form with a hidden field:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<input name="contacts" id="contacts_hidden" style="display:none">
</form>
<div id="contacts">
</div>
//your submit button and input
```

Now you can do:

```
contacts=[];
function addContact(){
         newcontact=document.getElementById("no");    
contacts.push(newcontact.value);
newcontact.value="";   
render();
}

function delete(i){
contacts.splice(i,1);
render();
}
//this takes the contacts array and adds it to the page + hidden submit field
function render(){
    hidden=document.getElementById("contacts_hidden");
all=document.getElementById("contacts");
content="";
for(i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
//add a delete button
content+=contacts[i]+"<a href='javascript:delete("+i+")'>Delete</a>";
}
all.innerHTML=content;
hidden.value=contacts.join(";");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas.However can you please tell me how I add the reset(clear) button along with each contact no so that I can clear a selected one if I need to